# How to use a Direct Line Speech Channel Bot with Python

Tags: python, azure, botframework, speech-to-text

I'm trying to setup a Microsoft Bot Framework bot using Python, a Direct Line Channel for Speech to Text and some Luis resources for NLP.

I've managed to get the bot working with Teams (and WebChat) but I can't figure how to correctly use the Direct Line Speech Channel. The bot is a variation of the [Multi-turn prompt bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/05.multi-turn-prompt) that I iterated upon (mostly by altering the dialog part, I didn't touch the rest of the bot).

I've tried following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directlinespeech?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), which led me to configure my Channel Registration and App service correctly. Following that, I've done some test using the clients provided [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Voice-Assistant/tree/master/clients) and got the following error on each and everyone of them:

`Connection was closed by the remote host. Error code: 1002. Error details: The server returned status code '503' when status code '101' was expected. SessionId: fc7a098e75e44379b18330e8385104a9`

This led me to believe that my bot was misbehaving and refusing Direct Line Speech messages.

Rereading the earlier tutorial led me to [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/directline-speech-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#feedback) which is where I am stuck. It asks to do a bunch of modifications on C# code so that the bot interpret and uses websockets correctly. However, my bot is written using the Python version of the SDK, and I can't find an equivalent tutorial for how to setup Direct Line Speech in a Python bot.

Could you advise me as to how I should go about it ? I'd prefer not to have to rewrite the whole thing in C#.

September 2020 edit: I've resorted to rewriting the whole thing in C#, it works now.

Comment: Do you understand that Direct Line and Direct Line Speech are two different channels?

Comment: I do, kind of. My question is asking about Direct Line Speech. I'll clarify.

Comment: It looks like your specific error is addressed in the [troubleshooting](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Voice-Assistant/tree/master/clients/csharp-wpf#troubleshooting) section of the WPF client, and it doesn't say anything about the bot misbehaving. However, if you'd like me to see about translating that C# advice to Python for you, can you pick a specific client that you'd like to get this to work with, and link to a specific Python sample that you'd like to make work with Direct Line Speech?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: I do, somewhat. I've resorted to rewriting my application in C# as the Python libraries supporting Direct Line Speech are simply not there. This should work now (other project going on, can't test extensively)

Comment: Hi, are you able to integrate Direct Line Speech with MS Teams? If yes, can you plz give some idea?